# Must have bought or leased before applying for entry?

Tags: spain, housing

I'm tagging this Spain, but I suspect they're not the only country doing this.  Three-page info sheet on visa application for long-stay includes:

> Only applications IN PERSON are accepted …
>   … process may take approximately 2 months from the day all documents are presented …
>   ORIGINAL and ONE PHOTOCOPY of each of the following …
>   3. Original Passport: Valid passp…. Your passport may remain at the Consulate.
>   8. House property or leasing contract in Spain.

So, if I take this literally, I am supposed to buy a round-trip ticket, skip classes to go to to Spain, find a house or apartment, buy it or sign a lease, return to USA and go in person to the consulate to seek permission to go live in it?  And I have to tell the seller or landlord that if I get permission, I won't move in for at least two months?

And I'm told that I can't buy or rent without a bank account and an NIE, and can't get a bank account or NIE¹ without an address.

I know there are Americans and other non-Spanish living there, so it must not be as silly as it sounds.  Advice?

¹Número de Identificación de Extranjero (Foreigner's ID number)

Comment: Where did you get this info? The only hit on google for your 8. appears to be a retirement residence visa, which wouldn't tend to be aimed at anybody who has classes to skip.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you told us about what kind of visa you're trying to get.

However, a lot of countries do this. French student visas involve this, for example.

Comment: Surprise, surprise!  Retired, 62 years young, and going to linguistics classes five days a week.  You CAN teach an old dog new tricks.  So they only do it for retirees?  Hmmmm.  What you found is probably the same document I found, or the equivalent from another embassy.  IIRC, the Spanish version from the Spanish government website said the same thing.

Comment: As you have probably just read above, it's a visa for long-stay for someone retired.  But that's not relevant to the question of how to handle restrictions that are on more than one type of visa.

Comment: Is it asking for proof of ownership or lease as a pre-requisite, or simply information on what you may have already have bought or rented in advance of the move to Spain?

Comment: I've located this on the [Consulate of Spain in Miami](http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Consulados/MIAMI/en/InformacionParaExtranjeros/Pages/Visa%20Requirements/Residence-Visa-for-Retirees.aspx) which notes at 10: Proof of accommodation in the city where you want to live as follows: • Notarized invitation letter from a family or friend where he/she assumes responsibility for lodging, **or**
• Lease, **or**
• Deed of the property **or**
• **Letter explaining the reason why you have chosen that city in particular.**

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, each consulate apparently writes up their own rules.  This one clearly lists it as a document that must be provided, with no sub-bullets.  San Francisco, IIRC, merely asked where you want to live.